# Formula to populate one column based on the value in another one

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to populate a column R with the value YES, if another column N has a value of NO.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IF`: http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/otherspreadsheets/qt/090808-google-spreadsheet-if-function.htm

The syntax for the IF function is: `=IF ( test, then_true, otherwise_value )`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to populate an entire column, you must use the `IF` function in combination with an `ARRAYFORMULA`. Add the following formula in `R1`:

### Formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(N:N="NO","YES", ""))
```

### Explained

It says, that if column N has an entry named "NO", then add "YES" in the corresponding R column. If the above criterion isn't met, then show nothing (""). The `ARRAYFORMULA` will make it possible to use a complete column range.

### Example

I've prepared an example file for you: **[using IF](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdDlHM3J4eUJ0SHRpeGlDQUhCRU1jc2c&usp=sharing)**